# SSIS OLEDB Destination Insert fail for Data Access Mode Table or View

Tags: sql-server, ssis, permissions, oledbconnection

I have OLEDB DEstination to insert to a table using Table or View Data Access Mode (Not Fast Load).
My table has a trigger AFTER INSERT, which will update a status.

When executing in Production, Package throws the below error.

```
SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  
An OLE DB error has occurred. 
Error code: 0x80004005.  
An OLE DB record is available.  
Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  
Hresult: 0x80004005  
Description: "Cannot find the object "MYTABLE_Response" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."
```

The table has permissions (SELECT/INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE)

It ran succcessfully in UAT but not in Prod.
Any response on this will be helpful.

Comment: Use the same credentials and try to access the Database using any tools ex: SQL Server Management Studio. If you have the access check whether the table exists or not. Also check your Connection properties in the OLEDB Destination.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible solutions:

1. Get the DBA to triple check that the account used in the connection manager has the
   appropriate access to the table/database.
2. Verify that when the package runs in Prod that it's connecting to the database that you expect it to connect to, i.e. is it configured/parameterized correctly?
3. Verify the table actually exists in Prod.